# How to count instances of string in a tab separated value file?

Tags: csv, awk, sed, scripting

How to count instances of strings in a tab separated value (tsv) file?

The tsv file has hundreds of millions of rows, each of which is of form

```
foobar1  1  xxx   yyy
foobar1  2  xxx   yyy
foobar2  2  xxx   yyy
foobar2  3  xxx   yyy
foobar1  3  xxx   zzz
```

.  How to count instances of each unique integer in the entire second column in the file, and ideally add the count as the fifth value in each row?

```
foobar1  1  xxx   yyy  1
foobar1  2  xxx   yyy  2
foobar2  2  xxx   yyy  2 
foobar2  3  xxx   yyy  2
foobar1  3  xxx   zzz  2
```

I prefer a solution using only UNIX command line stream processing programs.

Comment: pls paste some sample data, and your expecting output.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear what you want to do. Do you want to add 0/1 depending on the value of the second column as the fifth column or do you want to get the distribution of the values in the second column, total for the entire file?

In the first case, use something like `awk -F'\t' '{ if($2 == valueToCheck) { c = 1 } else { c = 0 }; print $0 "\t" c }' < file`.

In the second case, use something like `awk -F'\t' '{ h[$2] += 1 } END { for(val in h) print val ": " h[val] }' < file`.

Comment: The second case is what I believe is wanted, but it will take a second pass through the file to append the counts to the end of each line. It's possible to do it as you go, but the complexity would be increased and, in essence, it would still be two passes.

Comment: Will the applicability of the use of array `h[$2]` depend on how big the largest integer is?  Without checking, but it's possible some integer in the second column could be larger than largest machine number.

Answer (score 0):

One solution using `perl` assuming that values of second column are sorted, I mean, when found value `2`, all lines with same value will be consecutive. The script keeps lines until it finds a different value in second column, get the count, print them and frees memory, so shouldn't generate a problem regardless of how big is the input file:

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my (%lines, $count);

while ( <> ) { 

    ## Remove last '\n'.
    chomp;

    ## Split line in spaces.
    my @f = split;

    ## Assume as malformed line if it hasn't four fields and omit it.
    next unless @f == 4;

    ## Save lines in a hash until found a different value in second column.
    ## First line is special, because hash will always be empty.
    ## In last line avoid reading next one, otherwise I would lose lines
    ## saved in the hash.
    ## The hash will ony have one key at same time.
    if ( exists $lines{ $f[1] } or $. == 1 ) { 
        push @{ $lines{ $f[1] } }, $_; 
        ++$count;
        next if ! eof;
    }   

    ## At this point, the second field of the file has changed (or is last line), so 
    ## I will print previous lines saved in the hash, remove then and begin saving 
    ## lines with new value.

    ## The value of the second column will be the key of the hash, get it now.
    my ($key) = keys %lines;

    ## Read each line of the hash and print it appending the repeated lines as
    ## last field.
    while ( @{ $lines{ $key } } ) { 
        printf qq[%s\t%d\n], shift @{ $lines{ $key } }, $count;
    }   

    ## Clear hash.
    %lines = (); 

    ## Add current line to hash, initialize counter and repeat all process 
    ## until end of file.
    push @{ $lines{ $f[1] } }, $_; 
    $count = 1;
}
```

Content of `infile`:

```
foobar1  1  xxx   yyy
foobar1  2  xxx   yyy
foobar2  2  xxx   yyy
foobar2  3  xxx   yyy
foobar1  3  xxx   zzz
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl infile
```

With following output:

```
foobar1  1  xxx   yyy   1
foobar1  2  xxx   yyy   2
foobar2  2  xxx   yyy   2
foobar2  3  xxx   yyy   2
foobar1  3  xxx   zzz   2
```